# How can I solve Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe. error?

Tags: flutter, dart

After attaching animation code to my codes,I get such an error.

```
Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.

At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.

To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
```

[image: here you can see errors on console]

when I navigate any screen then get back,I encounter this problem.For better understanding I share my codes with you...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_raffle/constants/color_constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter_raffle/controllers/cart_controller.dart';
import 'package:flutter_raffle/models/cart_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_raffle/widgets/blinking_widget.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/linear_percent_indicator.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class SellingFastWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String imageUrl;
  final String productId;
  final String prizeText;
  final String buyText;
  final int soldAmount;
  final int totalAmount;
  final String progressColor;
  final VoidCallback onPressed;
  final bool isAnimating;

  const SellingFastWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.soldAmount,
    required this.totalAmount,
    required this.prizeText,
    required this.buyText,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.productId,
    required this.onPressed,
    required this.progressColor,
    required this.isAnimating,
  });

  @override
  State<SellingFastWidget> createState() => _SellingFastWidgetState();
}

class _SellingFastWidgetState extends State<SellingFastWidget>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller = AnimationController(
    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
    vsync: this,
  )..repeat();

  CartController controller = Get.find();
  bool isPlusTappedFirstly = false;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // TODO: implement dispose
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext contextt) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Row(
      children: [
        Stack(
          alignment: Alignment.topRight,
          children: [
            InkWell(
              onTap: widget.onPressed,
              child: Container(
                width: 163.4,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                    color: AppColors.standartWhiteColor),
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Positioned(
                      top: 46.6,
                      left: -21.5,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 60.58,
                        width: 193.5,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              fit: BoxFit.contain,
                              image: NetworkImage(widget.imageUrl)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Column(
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 9.32,
                        ),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: [
                            InkWell(
                              onTap: () async {
                                setState(() {
                                  isPlusTappedFirstly = true;
                                });
                                int number =
                                    await controller.getNumberOfCurrentElement(
                                        id: widget.productId);
                                controller.addToCart((CartModel(
                                    productId: widget.productId,
                                    availableNumber: widget.totalAmount,
                                    imageUrl: widget.imageUrl,
                                    numberOfOrder: number,
                                    prize: widget.prizeText,
                                    soldNumber: widget.soldAmount,
                                    whatYouWillBuy: widget.buyText)));
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 6.45),
                                height: 40,
                                width: 40,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                    image: const DecorationImage(
                                        image: AssetImage(
                                            'assets/images/plus.png'))),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(
                          height: 55.92,

                          ///
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              horizontal: 9.32,
                            ),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  width: 133.3,
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Prize: ${widget.prizeText}',
                                    maxLines: 2,
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      color: AppColors.textDarkColor,
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      fontFamily: 'Helvetica Neue',
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),

                                Container(
                                  width: 133.3,
                                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Buy: ${widget.buyText}',
                                    maxLines: 2,
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                    style: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xFFA1A1A1),
                                      fontSize: 11,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      fontFamily: 'Helvetica Neue',
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                // const Spacer(),
                                // Row(
                                //   children: [
                                //     const Text(
                                //       'Buy: ',
                                //       style: TextStyle(
                                //         color: Color(0xFFA2A2A2),
                                //         fontSize: 13,
                                //         fontFamily: 'Helvetica Neue',
                                //         fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                //       ),
                                //     ),
                                //     Expanded(
                                //       child: Text(
                                //         widget.buyText,
                                //         style: const TextStyle(
                                //           color: Color(0xFFA2A2A2),
                                //           fontSize: 13,
                                //           overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                //           fontFamily: 'Helvetica Neue',
                                //           fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                                //         ),
                                //       ),
                                //     ),
                                //   ],
                                // ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 6.524,
                                ),

                                widget.isAnimating
                                    ? BlinkingWidget(
                                        controller: _controller,
                                        child: LinearPercentIndicator(
                                            animation: true,
                                            barRadius:
                                                const Radius.circular(25),
                                            lineHeight: 18.64,
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                            progressColor: Color(int.parse(
                                                widget.progressColor)),
                                            percent: widget.soldAmount /
                                                widget.totalAmount,
                                            backgroundColor:
                                                const Color(0xffE6E6E6)),
                                      )
                                    : LinearPercentIndicator(
                                        animation: true,
                                        barRadius: const Radius.circular(25),
                                        lineHeight: 18.64,
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                                        progressColor: Color(
                                            int.parse(widget.progressColor)),
                                        percent: widget.soldAmount /
                                            widget.totalAmount,
                                        backgroundColor:
                                            const Color(0xffE6E6E6)),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  height: 9.32,
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      '${widget.soldAmount}',
                                      style: const TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 16,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                    Text(
                                      '/${widget.totalAmount} sold',
                                      style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                const Spacer()
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            if (isPlusTappedFirstly)
              AnimatedContainer(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 800),
                curve: Curves.bounceInOut,
                height: 130.48,
                width: 60.2,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: const Color(0xFFF4F4F4),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(17)),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () async {
                        int currentAmount = await controller
                            .getNumberOfCurrentElement(id: widget.productId);

                        await controller.addToCart(CartModel(
                            availableNumber: widget.totalAmount,
                            imageUrl: widget.imageUrl,
                            numberOfOrder: currentAmount,
                            prize: widget.prizeText,
                            soldNumber: widget.soldAmount,
                            whatYouWillBuy: widget.buyText,
                            productId: widget.productId));
                        setState(() {});
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 40,
                        width: 40,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            image: const DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage('assets/images/plus.png'))),
                      ),
                    ),
                    // GetBuilder(
                    //     init: CartController(),
                    //     builder: (context) {
                    //       return FutureBuilder(
                    //         future: controller.getNumberOfCurrentElement(
                    //             id: widget.productId),
                    //         builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    //           if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                    //               ConnectionState.waiting) {
                    //             return /*const Text(
                    //               '0',
                    //               style: TextStyle(
                    //                   fontSize: 16,
                    //                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                    //             )*/
                    //                 Container(
                    //               height: 20,
                    //               width: 20,
                    //               alignment: Alignment.center,
                    //               child: const CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    //             );
                    //           } else {
                    //             return Text(
                    //               '${snapshot.data ?? 0}',
                    //               style: const TextStyle(
                    //                   fontSize: 16,
                    //                   fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                    //             );
                    //           }
                    //         },
                    //       );
                    //     }),
                    InkWell(
                      onTap: () async {
                        int currentAmount = await controller
                            .getNumberOfCurrentElement(id: widget.productId);

                        controller.removeFromCart(CartModel(
                            availableNumber: widget.totalAmount,
                            imageUrl: widget.imageUrl,
                            numberOfOrder: currentAmount,
                            prize: widget.prizeText,
                            soldNumber: widget.soldAmount,
                            whatYouWillBuy: widget.buyText,
                            productId: widget.productId));
                        setState(() {
                          // if (currentAmount == 0) {
                          //   isPlusTappedFirstly = false;
                          // }
                        });
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        height: 40,
                        width: 40,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                            image: const DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage('assets/images/minus.png'))),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
        const SizedBox(
          width: 12.9,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BlinkingWidget extends AnimatedWidget {
  const BlinkingWidget({
    super.key,
    required AnimationController controller,
    this.child,
  }) : super(listenable: controller);
  final Widget? child;

  Animation<double> get _opacity => listenable as Animation<double>;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedOpacity(
      alwaysIncludeSemantics: true,
      // If the widget is visible, animate to 0.0 (invisible).
      // If the widget is hidden, animate to 1.0 (fully visible).
      opacity: _opacity.value > 0.5 ? 1 : 0.1,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      // The green box must be a child of the AnimatedOpacity widget.
      child: child ??
          Container(
            width: 200,
            height: 200,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

I am so sorry.The code is quite long,but for explaining celarly it was needed to share at least these code blocks

I tried to use didchangedependencies for solving this problem.I called _controller.dispose ...But it did not help me.